# Outlook preventing W10 from shutting down

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've searched all over Internet chat rooms for an answer on this issue with no success.

Windows 10 is fully up to date but since around the 1709 update my Office Outlook 16 client prevents W10 from shutting down with the message "Unread mail [email address] Outlook" which I have to Shut Down Anyway to close W10. (Unread email is the current Outlook folder open when I close down).

I have tried removing all add-ins; started it up in Safe Mode; used ScanPST to repair file but nothing has corrected the problem and tried repairing Outlook.

There are no other programs (that I know of) that could keep Outlook open.

I do not wish to reinstall Office so any other ideas would be welcome!